# showing that the certain functional transformation changes disagreement to agreement between two functions.

Tags: calculus

Let $f,g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$, both functions are strictly increasing and differentiable. Let $\Omega = \{x\in \mathbb{R}:f(x) \ne g(x)\}$ and Lebesgue measure of this set is positive, $\mu(\Omega)>0$.

I want to know if there exists functions $f,g$ such that
$$\sum_{m=1}^n a_mg(x)^m = \sum_{m=1}^nb_mf(x)^m, $$ 
almost everywhere in $\Omega$ for all $n$, where $a_n,b_n,a_1,b_1 \ne 0$, and $a_m$ and $b_m$ are real numbers.

Comment: Please revise your question.

Comment: Hmm. Why do you keep asking questions about $f(x) \ne g(x)$ and then applying some transformation and showing that $T(f(x)) \ne T(g(x))$? Just curious. Is there a motivation?

Comment: I think you copied the title of the previous quesiton and forgot to update it to a new title relevant to this one. Please revise and make the question clear.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why these quantities should be different.  Examples where they are sometimes equal are easy to construct.  For example, you might take $a_1 = 1$, $a_1' = a_2 = 2$, $a_2' = 3$, and for some $x \in [a,b]$, $f(x) = 1/3$ and $g(x) = 2/3$.

EDIT: Oops, just noticed the $a'$'s in $[0,1]$.  OK, just scale: take $a_1 = 1/4$, $a_1' = a_2 = 1/2$, $a_2' = 3/4$.

Comment: Here's one: Choose $a_1 = 1/4$, $a_2 = 3/4$, $s = 1/2$, as well as $a_1' = 2/9$, $a_2' = 2/3$, and $t = 3/4$. Then $a_1s^2 + a_2s(1-s) = a_1't^2 + a_2't(1-t)$. Now, set $g(x) = s$ and $f(x) = t$ for some $x\in [a,b]$ and extend $f$ and $g$ such that they satisfy the conditions.

Comment: I should have mentioned that almost everywhere. So can be equal sometimes can be ignored

Comment: With those same $a_1, \ldots, a_2'$, you have equality when $f(x) = \sqrt{g(x)^2 - g(x)/2}$.  For example, you could have $g(x) = x$ and $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 - x/2}$ for $x \in [a,b]$ as long as $1/2 \le a < b < 1$.